# React 'this' Context within Method

Tags: reactjs, binding, redux

I am trying to call a Method on a Button click like this (the button is returned within a method itself):

```
<button onClick={removeClick}>Remove</button>
```

this is the method i am trying to call

```
removeClick = event => {
    console.log('clicked');
};
```

im always getting errors like '_this2 is undefined'

i have already tried binding the method in the constructor.
an arrow function within the onClick didn't work as well

```
removeClick = event => {
    console.log('clicked');
};

renderWeather(cityData) {
    const name = cityData.city.name;
    const temps = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp - 273.15);
    const pressures = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
    const humidities = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
    const { lon, lat } = cityData.city.coord;

    return (
        <tr key={lon + lat}>
            <td>
                <GoogleMap lon={lon} lat={lat} />
                <span className="city-name">{name}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <WeatherChart data={temps} color="red" unit="°C" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <WeatherChart data={pressures} color="orange" unit="hPA" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <WeatherChart data={humidities} color="blue" unit="%" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onClick={this.removeClick}>Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Temperature (°C) </th>
                    <th>Pressure (hPA)</th>
                    <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ weather }) => ({
    weather
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
removeCity
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(WeatherList);
```

this is how the my component looks like

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: where `removeFunc` is defined?

Comment: it should be _removeClick_, messed up copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
renderWeather = cityData => {
...
}
```

and because you are using your clickhandler for a set of data you may want to pass some kind of identifier to it

```
removeClick = id => event => {
    console.log(`Removing data for ${id}`)
}
```

and call it by

```
<button onClick={() => {this.removeClick(id)}}>Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `this` as a second param to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
<tbody>{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather, this)}</tbody>
```

```js
class Item extends React.Component {

removeClick = event => {
    console.log('clicked');
}

renderWeather(cityData) {
    return <button onClick={this.removeClick}>Remove</button>     
}

render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Temperature (°C) </th>
                    <th>Pressure (hPA)</th>
                    <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather, this)}</tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
}

const weather = [
  {
    city: {name: '123'}
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
    <Item weather={weather} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: gives me the error _context.removeClick is not a funcion_ context beeing _this_